# Lazy loading ApplicationScoped beans in Quarkus test only works for the parent

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, junit5

I'm trying to implement tests for a quarkus app so that they work natively as well. I have two application scoped beans defined as such

```kotlin
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
class Client(
    @ConfigProperty(name = "FOO") val FOO String,
    @ConfigProperty(name = "BAR") val BAR: String,
) {
    ...
}
```

and another one, which depends on above `Client`

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class UseCases(
    private val client: Client
) {
    ...
}
```

In tests, I'm lazy loading these using constructors instead of using injection to enable native-tests as well, as follows

```kotlin
val client by lazy {
    Client("foo", "bar")
}
```

and

```
val useCases by lazy {
    useCases(client)
}
```

When I try to refer to these in the tests, any tests using `useCases` work fine, but any tests using `client` fail saying quarkus failed to start because

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Failed to load config value of type class java.lang.String for: FOOFailed to load config value of type class java.lang.String for: BAR
```

How could I define both beans in the tests so that I can use both for testing? I'm using `quarkus-junit5` for running tests.

Comment: You can't override beans when testing the native binary. The native binary is a black box test executed against the running (production) application.

Comment: @geoand I didn't realize I was overriding beans, though this doesn't work when running tests on jvm either. What would be an alternative approach to test both classes?